# Undefined method for Class in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

The following RSpec 2 test..

```
describe "GET new" do
  describe "gets a report form" do
    xhr :get, :new, :post_id => @post
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

gives this nice error:

`undefined method xhr for #<Class:0xb5c72404> (NoMethodError)`

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: are your tests nested in a `describe controller_name`?

Comment: yes, are there special rules how describe blocks should be nested?

Comment: Have you required `spec_helper`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out you have to use an `it` statement in the `describe` block. Then the error goes away. If you do not use the right amount of `describe` and `it` blocks, then RSpec produces all kinds of weird errors. This is the correct code:

```
describe "GET new" do
  it "gets a report form" do
    xhr :get, :new, :post_id => @post
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```